# How to pull a array element (which is document) in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose the collection is like this:

```
db.mytests.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb277b89b8295a790efde44"), 
"mylist": [ 
    { "foo1" :"bar1", "foo2" : "bar2" }, 
    {"foo1" : "bar3", "foo2" : "bar4" } 
], 
"nonlist" : "nonlistVal" }
```

I want to remove a document in `mylist` whose `foo1` equal to `bar1`, after reading [mongodb document about updating](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) I used this:

```
db.mytests.update({},{$pull:{'mylist':{'mylist.$.foo1':'bar1'}}})
```

but it failed. 
To figure out the problem I insert a new array into `mytests` using this:

```
db.mytests.update({},{$set:{'anotherList':[1,2,3,4]}})
```

and then using `db.mytests.update({},{$pull:{'anotherList':{$gt:3}}})` to pull the element
`4` in array `anotherList` ,it succeed.

I supposed the problem is with the `mylist.$.foo1` ? Can you tell me the right way to  remove a document element in a array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing:

```
db.mytests.update({},{$pull:{'mylist':{'mylist.$.foo1':'bar1'}}})
```

to:

```
db.mytests.update({},{$pull:{'mylist':{'foo1':'bar1'}}})
```

Comment: you may have to pass multi = true, since you're trying update all the document.